# Extracting text (in rendered order) using xPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Hiall,

I've been fighting with this for a couple of days now. I've pretty much tried everything I can think of and everything on the net. I'm trying to extract the text from a table (from each ) as rendered by the browser, regardless of the additional 's 's and 's (I'm sure there are other cases too). I think this pretty much shows the problem(I've kept it as short as possible).

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <table class='infobox vcard' style="font-size: 95%" id="sortable_table_id_0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/wiki/Germania_(airline)" title="Germania (airline)">Germania</a></td>
        <td><b>Seasonal</b>: Munich, Nuremberg [begins 31 July]
          <sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4"><span>[</span>5<span>]</span></a></sup>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The Best I've come up with so far is:

```
xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']/descendant::*[not(@class='reference') and text()]")
```

However, when I iterate through the array, the order of the text is incorrect. For instance, the last item () will come out as:

> Munich, Nuremberg [begins 31 July]
>   Seasonal 5 [ ]

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: Hi Steve,
Can you please write down what is the desired output that you want.
Because the xpath that you have written returns 6 results. or a node list containing 6 nodes.
Germania, : Munich, Nuremberg [begins 31 July], Seasonal, 5, [, ]

Comment: One: it seems that you're parsing XHTML. Why are you using XPath? there are probably easier ways to do what you want. What programming language are you using? If it's Java, I highly recommend to do this with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/): it probably takes 3-4 lines of Java :) P.S. You've signed your question with your name (Steve), so you're someone, not "No One" as your username suggests! :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick responses. I spent a good while deciding which forum to get involved in. Seems I picked the right one! The output I'm looking for is how it would appear on a webpage:  Germania Seasonal: Munich, Nuremberg [begins 31 July] [5]. I'm using PHP. Part of the reason for using xPath is to learn it. I'll check out jsoup, but I'd like to solve this in xPath too for my pride and sanity :-)

Comment: Actually, I made an improvement on my last expression: xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']/descendant::*[text()]/text()") - this preserves the order and I think is pretty close to what I want but it's not recursive. Maybe I just changed the question to: "Is there a way to get the rendered text (as seen in an HTML page) from a given element that takes into account all the recursive possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather surprised by these results. Technically XPath 1.0 returns a node-set, and a set has no defined ordering, so there is no guarantee of the order of results. (XSLT always processes XPath results in document order, but that doesn't mean XPath has to deliver them in document order.) In practice (and this becomes definitive in XPath 2.0) there is a high expectation that the results will be returned in document order, which is not what you are getting. Try a different XPath processor, preferably one that claims conformance to XPath 2.0, which is strict on this point.

Comment: Is there a different XPath processor in PHP that I can use? Or do I need to jump to a different platform? I'm not sure how to know if my PHP XPath library is 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Should I be using XSLT to scrape web pages and not XPath? - That's the builk of what I'm doing here. I need a good set of generic tools to extract data from (sometimes inconsistent) web sites.

Comment: I've opened a can of worms :-( XPath, XSLT, XQuery, JTidy, Tagsoup...I don't have time to learn all of these and make a decision on which is best to extract data from wikipedia - does anyone have an opinion?

Comment: Actually, I've realised you ARE getting results in document order, because you are selecting the elements, not the text nodes. The td element that is the parent of the text node "Munich, Nuremberg" appears in document order before its `<b>` element child, and therefore its content appears first. In fact, I would expect your expression to include the text "Seasonal" twice, because it is included in the string value of more than one selected element. I think you're really in XSLT territory here: you should be doing a recursive descent of the tree using xsl:apply-templates.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Seems like XSLT is worth spending some time on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']//text()[not(@class='reference')]")` get's me the following array:

```
['\n    ',
 '\n      ',
 '\n        ',
 'Germania',
 '\n        ',
 'Seasonal',
 ': Munich, Nuremberg [begins 31 July]\n          ',
 '[',
 '5',
 ']',
 '\n        ',
 '\n      ',
 '\n    ',
 '\n  ']
```

This seems to preserve the order.

Comment: Thanks. I will play with this and also spend some time looking into XSLT. For anyone reading in, XPath expressions ar used and expanded upon in XSLT, which may offer more flexibility. Thanks for your help.